# How are HTTP Cache-Control no-cache field names delimited?

Tags: http-headers

The syntax for the [HTTP Cache-Control no-cache](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-5.2.2.2) directive of a response allows a `field-name` argument.

RFC7234#5.2.2.2 says:

```
5.2.2.2.  no-cache

   Argument syntax:

      #field-name

   // ...

   If the no-cache response directive specifies one or more field-names,
   then a cache MAY use the response to satisfy a subsequent request,
   subject to any other restrictions on caching. 

   // ...
```

The specs state that the `no-cache` directive may "specif[y] one or more field-names". RFC7230#3.2 defines a `field-name` as being a token.

What the spec doesn't seem to cover is how multiple field names are delimited/separated.

How are Cache-Control no-cache field names delimited/separated?

**Example with no field name (most common usage)**

```
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

**Example with single field name (never personally seen it, technically valid)**

```
Cache-Control: no-cache=foo
```

**Multiple field names ?**

```
Cache-Control: no-cache=foo,bar
Cache-Control: no-cache=foo,bar
Cache-Control: no-cache=foo, bar
Cache-Control: max-age=60, private, no-cache=foo, bar, min-age=30
Cache-Control: max-age=60, private, no-cache="foo, bar", min-age=30
```

To me, only the last above example (the double-quoted `no-cache` value) is unambiguous.

What is the correct form to use?

I ask as I need to correctly parse arbitrary `Cache-Control` header values.

Answer (score 2):

RFC's BNF at [RFC2616#14.9](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.9) goes:

> `"no-cache" [ "=" <"> 1#field-name <"> ] ; Section 14.9.1`

[RFC2616#2.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#page-14) explains the `#` rule is a list:

> #rule  
>       A construct "#" is defined, similar to "*", for defining lists of  
>       elements. The full form is "#element" indicating at least  
>        and at most  elements, each separated by one or more commas  
>       (",") and OPTIONAL linear white space (LWS). This makes the usual  
>       form of lists very easy; a rule such as  
>          ( *LWS element *( *LWS "," *LWS element ))  
>       can be shown as  
>          1#element

[RFC2616#2.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#page-16) tells you `<">` just means `"`

> `<"> = <US-ASCII double-quote mark (34)>`

Therefore it would be `Cache-Control: max-age=60, private, no-cache="foo, bar", min-age=30`, as you did in your last one.

Comment: Thank you. [RFC 9111](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9111.html#name-no-cache-2) now obscures this detail even further, into the last paragraph talking about "quoted-string form".